# Vuex: how to map all state data to local properties?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to map all state data to local computed properties, a way to achieve it is

```
computed: {
      ...mapState([
          'data1',
          'data2',
          ...
      ]),
},
```

but if there are many data to pass, is there a simple way I can map all state data to local computed properties?

Comment: If you are ️ping a *lot* of VueX state into 1 component, then you might be have too much logic residing inside of 1 component. ‍♂️